# Define a task running for each build type in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am new in Gradle & implementing build script in Android Studio with Gradle. I have defined build types as following:

```
android {

 buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }

        other {
            ...
        }

        debug {
            ...
        }

  }
}
...
```

I need to create a task, which needs to be run for each build type, and it needs to know which build type it is running for:

```
task myTask(dependsOn: 'build'){
   //1. I need to be run for each build Type
   //2. I need to know which build type I am now running for
   buildType = XXX
}
```

How to implement myTask in gradle ?

Comment: A task can't be run more than once. Instead you need to declare a separate task per build type.

Comment: It's not clear what you need to do, but as Peter implies, you can dynamically define a "myTask$buildType" task (check "Dynamic tasks" in http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html).

Comment: Also, `dependsOn` simply means task `build` will be executed before `myTask`. Once `myTask` is executing, `build` will have already completed. You won't be able to intercept the currently running `buildType` afaik unless you modify the Android build process somehow.

Comment: I have the same exact problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a buildin support for accessing each buildVariant. for example to create one checkstyle task per variant you do this:

```
android{
    applicationVariants.all{ variant ->
       def checkstyleTask = task("${variant.name}Checkstyle", type:Checkstyle){
           ...
       }
       check.dependsOn checkstyleTask
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this point which **build type** it is running for?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a **buildConfigField** value for each type of build (i.e. `release`, `other`, `debug`).  Then in your task, you can check this field value to see what action you should take.  See here for an example:

https://azevedorafaela.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/environmental-variables-buildconfig-gradle-properties-and-android-studio/comment-page-1/#comment-821